# How can I create a zip file v2.0?

Tags: zip

How can I create a zip file **v2.0**?

It seems OpenDocument files are zip files v2.0:

```
$ file foo.odt
foo.odt: OpenDocument Text
$ hexdump -C -n 16 foo.odt
00000000  50 4b 03 04 14 00 00 08  00 00 03 0d 47 42 5e c6  |PK..........GB^.|
00000010
```

The fifth byte is `0x14`.

But if I unzip `foo.odt` and zip it back into `bar.odt`, I get a v1.0 zip file:

```
$ unzip -d foo foo.odt
$ cd foo/
$ zip -0 -X ../bar.odt mimetype
$ zip -r ../bar.odt * -x mimetype
$ file ../bar.odt
bar.odt: Zip archive data, at least v1.0 to extract
$ hexdump -C -n 16 ../bar.odt
00000000  50 4b 03 04 0a 00 00 00  00 00 00 90 46 42 5e c6  |PK..........FB^.|
00000010
```

The fifth byte is `0x0a`.

zip (2.32), Debian (6.0)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit: OK. Notice question has been updated so this <s>You do not get a v0.1 but v1.0.</s> does not longer apply.

The version is not "how capable" the file is but what **minimum** version is required to extract **that** file from within the archive.

This is **not** the overall version for the archive!

One difference here is that e.g. OO tags **all** files with same version requirement. That in turn is the file in the document (archive over all) with highest requirements.

That is. Each file has a zip-header that specify minimum version required to extract it. By the above we have typically:

```
  archive-files    PackType  Zip-Required OO-Header `zip`-header
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| mimetype         Store     1.0          2.0        1.0        |__ foo.odt
| content.xml      Deflate   2.0          2.0        2.0        |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
```

*So OO set required flag to 2.0 even though it is 1.0.* This does not, however, affect the ability to open the document. (It's OK to open a manually zip'ed file in OO even though `mimetype` is tagged with v1.0).

#### Versions

```
foo.odt:

1400   Version needed to extract.
0008   General Purpose
0000   Compression method
```

*Version needed to extract*, here the lower byte, `0x14`, is translated by dividing and modulus by 10:

```
Major: 0x14 / 0x0a = 2
Minor: 0x14 % 0x0a = 0
```

Aka Version 2.0

The higher byte `0x00` indicates what the file is compatible with. If zero, then it is compatible with MS-DOS (FAT, FAT32, VFAT). Else it is specified by a mapping. E.g. if I use `zip` with no options on my system I get a `0x03` which indicates Unix. `0x0a` is NTFS etc.

[Version 2.0 indicates:](http://www.pkware.com/documents/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT) *(4.4.3.2 Current minimum feature versions)*

```
* File is a folder (directory)
* File is compressed using Deflate compression
* File is encrypted using traditional PKWARE encryption
```

---

In you zip'ed file you have:

```
bar.odt:

0a00   Version needed to extract.
0000   General Purpose
0000   Compression method


Major: 0x0a / 0x0a = 1
Minor: 0x0a % 0x0a = 0
```

Aka version 1.0

---

Version 1.0 is simply default value.

#### File Hierarchy and minimum version

The reason you see version `1.0` under *Version needed to extract* - is that what you *actually see* is the zip-header for the file `mimetype`. This file is not deflated but stored with **no** compression. Thus you only need version `1.0` to extract that file. This, however, is not the overall version of the archive. If you look further down you'll find version 2.0 as soon as you find a file saved with deflating. You can check by e.g.:

```
hexdump -v -e '/1 "%02x "' bar.odt | grep -o '50 4b 03 04 .\{6\}'
```

Should give you something like

```
50 4b 03 04 0a 00 
50 4b 03 04 0a 00 
...
50 4b 03 04 14 00 
50 4b 03 04 14 00 
50 4b 03 04 0a 00 
50 4b 03 04 14 00 
...
```

Central directory file header

There are some file with an extended header. You can list these by:

```
hexdump -v -e '/1 "%02x "' foo.odt | grep -o '50 4b 01 02.\{16\}'
```

*(Remember to reverse `50 4b ...` to `02 01 4b 50` if hexdump -n 4 foo.odt say so)*

By this you'll get typically:

```
                  ____________ Version required (2.0)
                  |   |
50 4b 01 02 14 00 14 00 00 
50 4b 01 02 14 00 14 00 00 
50 4b 01 02 14 00 14 00 08
            |___| 
              |      
              +-------------- Version supported by packing application. v2.0
```

On the `zip` created file you could get get e.g.:

```
                  ____________ Version required for this file (2.0)
                  |   |
50 4b 01 02 1e 03 14 00 00
            |___| 
              |      
              +-------------- Version supported by packing 
                              application. v3.0
```

#### General purpose (and other flag set in odt files)

This is a bit flag. As your file is big-endian / Motorola, the flag becomes:

```
0x0800 = 0000 1000 0000 0000
              |
              +---------------- 11 => File names and comments MUST be 
                                      stored as Utf-8.
```

At least LibreOffice saves further with various mods.

`mimetype` is always first and should not be compressed. This is to help various software to identify the file and its content. By this one can e.g.:

$ hexdump -C -s 38 -n 39 foo.odt

```
00000026  61 70 70 6c 69 63 61 74  69 6f 6e 2f 76 6e 64 2e  |application/vnd.|
00000036  6f 61 73 69 73 2e 6f 70  65 6e 64 6f 63 75 6d 65  |oasis.opendocume|
00000046  6e 74 2e 74 65 78 74                              |nt.text|
```

While `zip` typically saves all directories, OO saves only a directory if it is empty. Thus:

zip:

```
Thumbnails/
Thumbnails/thumbnail.png
META-INF/
META-INF/manifest.xml
```

oo:

```
Thumbnails/thumbnail.png
META-INF/manifest.xml
```

And so on ...

Answer (score 2):

An ODF document is a zip file, as you state. Look at Wikipedia's [entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenDocument_technical_specification). The [zip format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_%28file_format%29) is supposed to have the version in 2 bytes, little endian, at offset 4. A header starts `0x04034b50` (little endian, check), version in two bytes (`0x000a` in your self-compressed case, `0x0014` in your ODT and in one I've lying around here from 2006). The format accomodates different versions.

My local `zip(1L)` and `unzip(1L)` man pages are totally silent on formats handled, unfortunately. My current zip creates version `0x0014` (zip-3.0-5.fc18.x86_64, Fedora 18). It looks like you need zip version 3 or so.